# Authenticating a specific user via the graph api, and posting to their wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to figure out if it would be possible to authenticate a specific user, with said users username and password using the graph api, and the posting a message to their wall.

Is this a possibility with the graph api?

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can present users with a webpage (provided by facebook) for entering their credentials.  Facebook will then give you back a 'token' which you can pass into the Graph API to do things on that user's behalf.  Read more about this at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Comment: So I don't need to register an application to do this?

Comment: you do need to do that... it's trivial though